# Is possible for grep to see the exact word?

Tags: grep

Is possible for grep, or egrep to see the exact word?
See this example: those are my groups

```
groups
floppy audio video cdrom games plugdev power netdev scanner users
```

I want to see only power, but return the entire line

```
groups |grep --color -w power
floppy audio video cdrom games plugdev power netdev scanner users
```

Is easy to return only power using pipe with awk or cut

```
groups |grep --color -w power|cut -d ' ' -f 9
power
```

but my question is: is possible for grep or egrep command to return the exact word only?

Comment: FYI `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`. Similarly `fgrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -F`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with `GNU grep` as in `grep -o power`.

According to [grep manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

> -o, --only-matching

> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching
> line, with each such part on a separate output line.